# How to convert Japanese characters to Latin characters?

Tags: .net, winforms, unicode

I try to program an application to convert foreign characters.
     **how can i convert Japanese character か to ka?** 
I am still in research mode of UCD data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert language characters to Latin alphabet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371565/convert-language-characters-to-latin-alphabet)

Comment: @DannyBeckett : Yes i know ,i am working on the first step to get some hints

Comment: Are you only looking to convert hiragana/katakana, or do you want kanji as well? The first one is easy; the second not so much.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen : thanks for your reply. I am looking for both .but will be okay if i achieve first one as of now,later will try to do the second one.