# QlineEdit with Japanese characters

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a main widget in my application when I type something I display a child widget with `lineEdit` in it.If the input language is Japanese and I press any key then widget with line edit in it will appear with first character typed (`lineEdit->setText("h")`) and if I continue typing the next character should also appear. Now the issue which I am facing is that how to make the second character really "part" of the first character.

> First letter is  "h"
>   second letter is "e".
>   CASE 1 : When "h" is not part of "e" ,it will appear like"　h エ".
>   CASE 2 : When h and e are combined in Japanese it looks like "ヘ".

I want to achieve case 2.

What I have tried:
Enabled the `setAttribute( Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, true );` on my `lineEdit`
and also captured the `QEvent::InputMethod` but then I am not able to combine the first letter and subsequent letters user types.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure but with Japanese locale set and UTF-16 it should work, or not? Or you are trying to write Japanese with English locale? Maybe write the setting of OS and and App.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chinese. Is your keyboard settings on japanese?

Comment: @Radek Yes I am trying to Japanese with English locale.I didnt understand your last comment.

Comment: @JoeyRoosing What works for you?Yes I change the language to Japanese from the language bar on Windows.Assume you have a QMainWindow which displays a line edit whenever QInputMethod event is triggered on main window.Now the problem is that how to combine the first charcter and the characters to follow.

Comment: @Metoo I think I understand your problem now. Do you have a handler that catches the edit event? You might somehow need to check the first character and second character, see if the two conform to a UTF-8 representation, and transform it to that. When I type Chinese, using the windows chinese keyboard, when I enter a word that exists of two characters, windows first suggest the characters, you select which one, and that is the character that gets input. I don't know how it works for japanese. But it sounds you might be stuck with UTF-8 code point matching.

Comment: @JoeyRoosing On the main window I catch the input method event and on that event I display my line edit.I am typing Japanese using a latin keyboard.Can you may be post some code and show me how you have done that.Also I didnt quite understand some part of your comment "transform it to that."Can you please explain a bit more.Some code will immensely help.

Comment: @Metoo sorry, for now I can not provide any code at this moment. But I think you are looking for transliteration software. Unfortunately, I don't know any C++ transliteration API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371565/convert-language-characters-to-latin-alphabet for info on what it means. I know google has an api, but I don't know any details about that.